# dafny pre-condition failure

Tags: dafny, preconditions

- I'm trying to run a dafny verified version of BFS (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202757/proving-termination-of-bfs-with-dafny))
- My input graph is perfectly fine, but for some reason it fails the pre-condition check.
- Here is the [permalink](https://www.rise4fun.com/Dafny/cvpl1)
- And for self completeness here is the graph definition + validity conditions

```
class Graph
{
    var adjList : seq<seq<int>>;
    constructor (adjListInput : seq<seq<int>>)
    {
        adjList := adjListInput;
    }
}
function ValidGraph(G : Graph) : bool
    reads G
{
    (forall u :: 0 <= u < |G.adjList| ==> forall v   :: 0 <= v <     |G.adjList[u]| ==> 0 <= G.adjList[u][v] < |G.adjList|) &&
    (forall u :: 0 <= u < |G.adjList| ==> forall v,w :: 0 <= v < w < |G.adjList[u]| ==> G.adjList[u][v] != G.adjList[u][w])
}
method main()
{
    var G : Graph := new Graph([[1,2],[0,2],[0,1]]);
    assert (ValidGraph(G));
}
```

- dafny's response is `Error: assertion violation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `ensures adjList == adjListInput` to the constructor. Because Dafny treats a constructor basically just like a method, and because Dafny analyzes each method in isolation, when Dafny analyzes `main`, it only uses the specification of the constructor, not the body of the constructor. So the reason the assert was failing was because from the perspective of `main`, the constructor was setting the field `adjList` to an arbitrary value that did not necessarily correspond to its argument.