# dafny non aliased memory weird behavior

Tags: alias, memory-model, dafny

I have a dafny defined graph ADT (from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63265121/dafny-pre-condition-failure)) brought here again for completeness:

```
class Graph
{
    var adjList : seq<seq<int>>;
    constructor (adjListInput : seq<seq<int>>)
        ensures adjList == adjListInput
    {
        adjList := adjListInput;
    }
}
function ValidGraph(G : Graph) : bool
    reads G
{
    (forall u :: 0 <= u < |G.adjList| ==> forall v   :: 0 <= v <     |G.adjList[u]| ==> 0 <= G.adjList[u][v] < |G.adjList|) &&
    (forall u :: 0 <= u < |G.adjList| ==> forall v,w :: 0 <= v < w < |G.adjList[u]| ==> G.adjList[u][v] != G.adjList[u][w])
}
method main()
{
    var G : Graph := new Graph([[1,2],[0,2],[0,1]]);
    var nonRelatedArray := new int[8];
    var i := 0; while (i < 14)
    {
        // nonRelatedArray[3] := 55;
        i := i + 1;
    }
    assert (ValidGraph(G));
}
```

If I remove the write comment to `nonRelatedArray` at index `3`, I get an **assertion violation**, which is a bit weird because it seems reasonable that the memory model would be able to determine that `nonRelatedArray` is (well) non related to `G`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `modifies nonRelatedArray` to the loop. The key to this modifies clause is that it does not mention `G`. So then Dafny knows that `G` will not be modified by the loop, so it will still be a valid graph.

It is a little confusing what happens if you leave off a modifies clause from a loop. If you don't do any writes to the heap (like when you comment out the write above), then Dafny (actually, Boogie) is able to automatically see that nothing is changed at all. But if you do any writes into the heap, Dafny's default modifies clause all of a sudden becomes "anything the surrounding scope is allowed to modify". If you want something other than these two defaults, you need to ask for it explicitly by giving a modifies clause.